# ExtJs DateField submits seconds instead of date on form submission

Tags: extjs

I have a form, developed using ExtJs, which contains the DateField, on form submission, the date gets submitted in seconds rather than the format I defined.

My problem is: I want to submit the date in the same format like its defined in the format property.

Below is the DateField code snippet:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date',{
        fieldLabel: 'Date1',
        name: 'date1',
        id: 'date1',
        allowBlank: true,
        format: 'Y-m-d',
        submitFormat: 'Y-m-d',
    })
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me to figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Currently you are getting in this format `m/d/Y` ? This one is default.

Comment: @UDID, No I get them in seconds, like for e.g. 1472063400

Comment: I answered this. Please check and try which I suggest.

Comment: Please post the code where you submit the form.

Comment: @Alexander Actually on form submission I am trying to get the data through `form->getRecord()` because I have multiple popups on my page and I need the whole page data so. And form->getRecord(), returns the seconds while if I debug and check the submitted record, it contains the correct date object.

Answer (score 2):

In date fields format it leads Defaults to: `"m/d/Y"` [DateDoc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/Ext.form.field.Date.html). Your  format must be valid according to Ext.Date#parse.[Date Parse](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/Ext.Date.html#method-parse/)

To make your desire format you must have to use Ext.Date#parse.

```
dt = Ext.Date.parse("2006-01-15", "Y-m-d");
```

Refer the link for date parsing.

I created a fiddler for you. Please check [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f2f)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But even if I try to use the default format i.e. "m/d/Y" still it keeps submitting the value in seconds only i.e. like 1472063400

Comment: for all the dates you getting the same value 1472063400 ?

Comment: I checked your fiddle, and yes it works there, but I am wondering why it does not work when I do implement it in my project.

Comment: I assume we are missing something in your project. Clear the cache and try once. Also give few more information or codes to understand it better.

Comment: Actually on form submission I am trying to get the data through `form->getRecord()` because I have multiple popups on my page and I need the whole page data so. And `form->getRecord()`, returns the seconds while if I debug and check the submitted record, it contains the correct date object.

Answer (score 0):

`Form.getRecord` returns to you a model instance, [as per the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-getRecord).

A model instance has fields which are have defined value types, [as per the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-fields). If your field is defined as an int field, and not a date, you get the seconds. If you define it as a date field, you get the javascript date.

Depending on how you actually send that model to the server, you will have to manually format the date from the model into the desired string using `Ext.Date.format`, or you may be able to use the `dateWriteFormat` config of the field, [as per the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.data.field.Date.html#cfg-dateWriteFormat).